# What is the name of the effective address part that is not the bank?

Tags: emulation, addressing-mode

I'm writing a SNES emulator for fun, and I always wondered what is the name of the part that is not the bank:

```
Effective address: $80       $0000
                   ^-- Bank  ^-- ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per page 8 of [the W65C816S data sheet](http://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/documentation/w65c816s.pdf):

> During modes of operation, the 8-bit Data Bank Register holds the bank address for memory transfers. The 24-bit address is composed of the 16-bit instruction effective address and the 8-bit Data Bank address.

And, similarly, on page 9:

> The 8-bit Program Bank Register holds the bank address for all instruction fetches. The 24-bit address consists of the 16-bit instruction effective address and the 8-bit Program Bank address.

So "instruction effective address" seems to be Western Digital's phrase for the low 16 bits.

I would dare imagine 'offset' is also commonly used though, through similarity to Intel's more-widely-familiar real mode [segment:offset addressing scheme](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html).